# change order of elements inside linked list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use simple linked list:

```
struct index
{
   struct index* next_element;
   int data;
   struct index* previous_element;
}
```

What is the best way to change order of elements in terms of performance?
For example, i have 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 and i need  1 4 2 3 5 6 7 8.

Comment: What is your criterion for the reordering? It is very difficult to help without knowing what kind reordering you are after.

Comment: That `index` is a bad misnomer, as it isn't an index, but a list node. Also, in C++ you don't need to precede struct names with `struct` (`index* next_element;` and `index* previous_element` will do). Oh, and to answer your question: You swap the pointers. Hard to get faster than that.

Comment: It is index, it's just simplified piece of code. Data behind index is large array of strings.

Comment: @qutron: You need to properly @address comment replies so that they show up on the Responses tab of those you answer to. (I only saw this one by accident.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell in general. It seems that you want to move element 4 after element 1. Do you have the `index*` for both? Or do you just know that the fourth element has to move by two places? This obviously affects the amount of listwalking you have to do.

In general, for maximum efficiency, you'd want a function

```
void list_remove_unsafe_(index* i) {
  // These two have to change (minimum needed)
  i->previous_element->next_element = i->next_element;
  i->next_element->previous_element-> = i->previous_element;
  // We leave i itself unchanged (dangling)
}
```

and a follow-up

```
void list_insert_unsafe_(index* after, index* i) {
  // These four have to change (minimum needed)
  index* before = after->next_element;
  i->previous_element = after;
  i->next_element = before;
  before->previous_element = i;
  after->next_element = i;
}
```

These operations are unsafe because they temporarily leave the list in a broken state and make lots of assumptions (e.g. no check for begin/end of lists). Those need special handling. For the basic operation these 6 pointer writes are the bare minimum.